# C++ convert boost::optional<double> to double

Tags: c++, boost, double, option-type

In C++ is it possible to convert  boost::optional to double?

I.E.

```
boost::optional<double> time;
double realTime;

realTime = time;
```

The last line gives me an error that I

```
"Assigning to 'double' from incompatible type boost::optional<double>"
```

Comment: Start with documentation, this is what documentation is for: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/quick_start.html

Comment: So, what do you want to happen when `time` is not a `double`?  (An `optional<double>` is a maybe-double, and maybe-nothing).

Comment: @Yakk: Zero seems like a reasonable substitute for maybe-nothing.

Comment: @RobertHarvey What, not `NaN`?  Heck, in some cases, `-inf` or `+inf` are reasonable (say, a cumulative max or min).  My point is that you need to answer the question, and think about it, when you do it.  Any default will be poor in some cases.

Comment: @Yakk: NaN would work, although I would imagine that is going to be problematic in some scenarios.  It's a lossy conversion anyway; any choice is going to be a compromise of some sort.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I vote for `3` myself.  It isn't `0` or `NaN`, which is a plus, nor is it `1`, `0` or `-1` or infinity.  I mean, if you are going to have some arbitrary flag value, make it cost something.

Comment: Whatever floats your boat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course it is, but you need to check if `time` is given.

```
if (time){
    /*this means that the optional parameter was provided*/
    realTime = *time;
}
```

Boost uses the *dereference* operator to extract the value from the optional, and uses some more operator overloading trickery to make `if (time)` a satisfactory test of "provided-ness".

Comment: Nice, that compiles!  I did check if time existed as - if (time) but I didn't realize the pointer compiles.  Now onto the tests!

Comment: But do read the documentation. It's very comprehensive and even tells you how `optional` is implemented.

Comment: I did read the documentation and the web for a day.  Of course I didn't read everything, so I will continue my reading.  I asked the question to understand if it was possible.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you know what value you want to set `time` to if the `optional` is missing, `opt.get_value_or(3)` will return the value of the `opt`, and if it has no value it will return `3`.

This is dangerous, as most default values are problematic (`0`, `3`, `NaN`, `+inf`, `-inf` are all worth considering.  `3` because at least it isn't one of the others.)

Once you know the optional has a value, `.get()` or unary `operator*` will extract it.  Evaluating an `optional<?>` in a boolean context will tell you if it is empty.